# Installation for maven in eclipse Mars

Tags: maven

As i am working in MNC company, we need to install maven in my eclipse.but Eclipse MarketPlace & Install New Software is blocked in my Firewall.

And also tried : windows-->Properties-->Advanced System Setting (this also blocked)

Can u please help any one to install maven.

Thanks

Comment: Try to use the offical site https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi and download maven via browser...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply install maven in offline mode. It has a lot of dependencies and their dependencies. This will become a very tedious task to do manually.

Consider these options:

1. If you can connect to internet through other means, like using a
   proxy, try configuring proxy to install maven. See [Configuring a
   proxy.](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html)
2. Better talk with your network IT team, they will sort it out for you by providing some exceptional access on 8080/80 ports

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try it out and set the proxy from your company in eclipse and try again. Maybe you have no network configuration in eclipse so the Firewall blocks everything.

Comment: where we need to set proxy in my eclipse

Comment: Well vivek mano gave you an answer on how to configure a proxy. Otherwise you can look in eclipse for something like preferences -> Network Connections or something like that.